# How to deal wih a horizontally and vertically expandable card using grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, styled-components

### Goal:

I'm trying to build an responsive list layout with an expandable card, the goal would be this:

[image: list layout with expandable card]

### Attempt:

I build the card, on a separated component called *MaterialCard* and tried to organize all the cards on a component called *MaterialCardList*.

*MaterialCard:*

This component expands horizontally through max-width and isExpanded boolean expands it vertically adding content to the card.

```
  export const MaterialCard: React.FC<IMaterialCard> = ({ material }) => {

  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (

    <CustomContainer  onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)} style={isExpanded ? { maxWidth: 635 } : {maxWidth: 310 }}>

...
```

*MaterialCardList:*
Here is where all MaterialCard are rendered, and the main problem as I see

```
export const MaterialCardList: React.FC = () => {


  return (
    <Organizer>
      {!!materials.length && materials.map((material) => (
          <MaterialCard  key={material.id} material={material} />
      ))}

    </Organizer>
  )
}
```

*Organizer:*

This is the styled-component of the MaterialCardList

```
export const Organizer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 310px));
    grid-column-gap: 16px;
    grid-row-gap: 16px;
`;
```

The result was something like this:

[image: attempt result]

I understand that minmax on grid does not let my card open the width, but i don't know where to go from here to achieve the layout, there any easier way to do this without grid? What next step to achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal is a 2 dimensional layout, I think `grid` is still a suitable approach for it.

The following is a basic example that defines a fixed number of columns based on responsive value. It specifies an explicit position for the `expanded` card ,and let other cards fill the gap by auto placement.

Live of the example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-wyam2f?file=src/App.tsx)

The `MaterialCardList` component could use media queries to define the number of columns needed here, or it could be fixed depending on the use case.

```
const Organizer = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 24px;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 900px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  @media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
`;

const MaterialCardList = ({ materialData }: IMaterialCardList) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState<number | null>(null);
  return (
    <Organizer>
      {materialData.map((item, index) => (
        <MaterialCard
          material={item}
          key={item}
          index={index}
          isExpanded={index === expanded}
          onToggleExpand={() =>
            setExpanded((prev) => (prev === null ? index : null))
          }
        />
      ))}
    </Organizer>
  );
};
```

The `MaterialCard` component specifies an explicit position for the `expanded` card based on its `index` and the columns of the grid.

While media queries are used in `StyledCard`, they are just for getting the column number of the grid, and can be omitted if the component can get responsive props for this, either from a helper hook or an UI library used in addition to `styled-components`.

```
interface IStyledCard {
  readonly isExpanded?: boolean;
  readonly index: number;
}

const StyledCard = styled.div<IStyledCard>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: 5px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 1px 1px darkgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  grid-column-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
    !isExpanded ? "auto" : (index + 1) % 2 === 0 ? "1" : `${(index % 2) + 1}`};
  grid-column-end: ${({ isExpanded }) => (isExpanded ? "span 2" : "span 1")};
  grid-row-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
    isExpanded ? `${Math.floor(index / 2 + 1)}` : "auto"};
  grid-row-end: ${({ isExpanded }) => (isExpanded ? "span 2" : "span 1")};
  @media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    grid-column-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
      !isExpanded
        ? "auto"
        : (index + 1) % 3 === 0
        ? "2"
        : `${(index % 3) + 1}`};
    grid-row-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
      isExpanded ? `${Math.floor(index / 3 + 1)}` : "auto"};
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    grid-column-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
      !isExpanded
        ? "auto"
        : (index + 1) % 4 === 0
        ? "3"
        : `${(index % 4) + 1}`};
    grid-row-start: ${({ isExpanded, index }) =>
      isExpanded ? `${Math.floor(index / 4 + 1)}` : "auto"};
  }
`;

interface IMaterialCard {
  readonly material: string;
  readonly index: number;
  readonly isExpanded: boolean;
  readonly onToggleExpand: () => void;
}

const MaterialCard = ({
  material,
  index,
  isExpanded,
  onToggleExpand,
}: IMaterialCard) => {
  return (
    <StyledCard isExpanded={isExpanded} index={index} onClick={onToggleExpand}>
      {material}
    </StyledCard>
  );
};
```

The explicit position for `expanded` item is only basic here, which could use a lot of adjustments to be more natural, and perhaps further customization could also be done to support multiple `expanded` items if needed.

If the layout also need to be animated, perhaps the easiest way could be using a library with built-in support for layout animations such as [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/).

Here is a basic example with animation: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-zxpre9?file=src/App.tsx)